# Is there a list of "potentially dangerous Request.Path" values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I want to generate slugs for my pages. To that end, I want to remove all the "dangerous request paths".

Is there a list anywhere, or is there a way to find out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no definitive list of rules that will fire this exception, but quite a detailed description of the theory, over-rides ect can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx

Comment: Hmm... this is actually made even more complicated by the fact that I need to change accented characters to non-accented, and actualy URL encode Japanese.